# How to access mysqli connection in another class on another page?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

How can I open a database connection in user class , where I can do database operation?
and why need to define inbuilt created functions in DBConnection class ..????

I have created

1. db.php
2. user.php
3. result.php

**in db.php**

```
class DBConnection  
{       
  protected $mysqli;
  private  $db_host="127.0.0.1";
  private  $db_name="test";
  private  $db_username="root";
  private  $db_password="";

  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mysqli=new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_username,
                $this->  db_password,$this->db_name) or die($this->mysqli->error);

         return $this->mysqli;
    }

public function query($query)  // why i need to creat this function
     {
    return $this->mysqli->query($query);
     }

public function real_escape_string($str)
 {
    return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string();
 }


   function __destruct(){
     //Close the Connection
     $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
?>
```

**in User.php**

```
<?php
  require "db.php"; 

  class User {  

  public function __construct($conn)
{
    $this->mysqli=$conn;

}

   public function addUser($name,$username,$email,$pwd)
   {
     $query="  ";

     $res=$this->mysqli->query($query);

  //pls chek the query function in DBConnection,what is the need to define query               >       function in DBConnection ?

    return $res;
    }
   }    
?>
```

**in result.php**

```
    <?php

      require "user.php";

      $conn=new DBConnection();

      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
```

> ```
>  $name = $conn->real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])));
>    $username =  $conn->real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['username'])));
>    $email =     $conn->real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])));
>    $password    = $conn->real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['pass'])));
> ```

```
//echo $name."".$username."".$email."".$password;
  $uObj=new User($conn);
  $uObj->addUser($name,$username,$email,$password);


echo " hi your name is <I>".$name."</I> and your email ID is <I>".$email."</I>";
        }


?>
```

Comment: It's not clear where `User` class gets its `->mysqli` property from. Is `User` a subclass of `DBConnection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DBConnection` class would need an additional method:

```
public function getLink()
{
    return $this->mysqli;
}
```

It seems that your original `User` class was a subclass of `DBConnection`, because `mysqli` property on `DBConnection` is `protected` and `User` class has a `parent::__construct()` call.

It's better to use dependency injection, so your `User` class will receive its database connection via the constructor:

```
public function __construct(DBConnection $db)
{
    $this->mysqli = $db->getLink();
}
```

Then from your code you can run:

```
$db = new DBConnection;
$uObj = new User($db);
```

Comment: but to do insertion operation i am not able to fire query inside user class in insert function.      >addUser($name,$username,$email,$pwd)
>      {
>       
>               $query="  ";
>                                 
>               $res=$this->mysqli->query($query);
>                //i want to fire inser query here .... but i am not able to to do that               
>               return $res;
>      }

Comment: @user1055480 your question is vague, but I've updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: the another way is that.<pre> u pass object of db while creating object of User `$uOBj=new User(new DBCOnnection); `is it correct way to get connection..???</pre>

Comment: @user1055480 I don't know why you added `query` and `escape` methods on your `DBConnection`; they don't make sense; just use `getLink()` as I suggested so that you have direct access to `mysqli`.

Comment: still i am not able to acess inbuilt method when i am trying >$name=$uObj->real_escape_string($name);   >i am getting error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::real_escape_string()"