# Running a mysqli prepare statement inside my own class

Tags: php, class, mysqli, inner-classes, prepare

there has been a similar topic ([How to access mysqli connection in another class on another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113080/how-to-access-mysqli-connection-in-another-class-on-another-page)) but it doesn't quite answer my question, or I'm missing the point.  I'm trying to build a class which will allow me to quickly build the bones of a slideshow by pulling a set of image urls and div ids from a database.  Here's what I've managed:

```
      class make_slide 
  {
    private $slide_mysqli;
    public $get_slide;
    public $single_slide;
    public $get_imgurl1; 
    public $get_imgurl2; 
    public $get_imgurl3; 
    public $get_imgurl4; 
    public $get_imgurl5; 
    public $get_imgid1; 
    public $get_imgid2; 
    public $get_imgid3; 
    public $get_imgid4; 
    public $get_imgid5; 

    function __construct(){
    $this->slide_mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','user', 'password','database') or die($this->mysqli->error);
    }

    function get_slides ($page) 
    {
      if ($this->get_slide = $this->slide_mysqli->prepare('SELECT IMAGE_URL1, IMAGE_URL2, IMAGE_URL3, IMAGE_URL4, IMAGE_URL5, IMAGE_ID1, IMAGE_ID2, IMAGE_ID3, IMAGE_ID4, IMAGE_ID5 FROM Page WHERE ID=? AND IMAGE_URL1 != NULL')) 
      {
        $this->get_slide->bind_param('s', $page);
        $this->get_slide->bind_result($this->get_imgurl1, $this->get_imgurl2, $this->get_imgurl3, $this->get_imgurl4, $this->get_imgurl5, $this->get_imgid1, $this->get_imgid2, $this->get_imgid3, $this->get_imgid4, $this->get_imgid5); 
        $this->get_slide->execute();
        $this->get_slide->store_result();         
        $this->get_slide->fetch();
        $this->get_slide->free_result();
        $this->get_slide->close();  
      }
      //print the slideshow out here... for example
      print '<br><img src="http://***.com/'.$this->get_imgurl1.'" alt="'.$this->get_imgid1.'" height="200"/></div>';
      print '<br><img src="http://***.com/'.$this->get_imgurl1.'" alt="'.$this->get_imgid2.'" height="200"/></div>';

    }
  }
```

so now if I run the following, the class will do all the work for me:

```
  $slide = new make_slide();
  $slide->get_slides('home');
```

only it's printing the images but disregarding the stuff I've pulled from the database.
I check the error logs and I'm told

> PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant IMAGE_ID5 - assumed 'IMAGE_ID5'
>   in /var/www/***/***.com/httpdocs/index.php on line 216, referer:
>   http://***.com/index.php

please, any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which one is line 216?

Comment: A multi-dimensional array would make your life a bit easier I think.

Comment: The errant code can't be what you have posted here.  The cause of `undefined constant IMAGE_ID5` would be most likely a variable missing its `$`, but the only place that string appears in the code above is inside the SQL statement string where it would not be parsed as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: **DO NOT use mysqli** unless you're not going to use prepared statements or limit yourself to very easy statements from beginner's manual.
Whatever complex usage of mysqli prepared statements like using it inside of your own class **is a nightmare.**

Use PDO instead.
With PDO ALL your code will take one small function:

```
function get_slides ($page) 
{
    global $pdo;
    $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM Page WHERE ID=? AND IMAGE_URL1 != NULL');
    $stm = $pdo->execute(array($page));
    $row = $stm->fetch();
    foreach ($row as $img) {
        print "<br><img src='http://***.com/$img' alt='$img' height='200'/></div>";
    }
}
```

However, as you'vebeen told in the comments, your error is irrelevant to the code you posted here.